# Is it possible to make more than one columns combinedly unique in a oracle table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

The question might not be that understandable.

I have created two tables - films(FILMAS) and cinema halls(ZALES). The relationship between them is M:M, so the table sessions(SEANSI) was created to link them.

Is it possible to ensure that at the same date and time there can not be two different sessions in one cinema hall? How?

Oracle 18c XE database

```
CREATE SEQUENCE zlid_seq;

CREATE TABLE ZALES(
    Z_ID INTEGER DEFAULT zlid_seq.NEXTVAL CONSTRAINT ZL_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    ZNOSAUKUMS VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    IETILPIBA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ATVERTS BOOLEAN DEFAULT(YES),
    ID_K INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_KT FOREIGN KEY (ID_K) REFERENCES KINOTEATRI(K_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE FILMAS(
    F_ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT FM_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    FNOSAUKUMS VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PR_DATUMS DATE NOT NULL,
    ZANRS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FM_ZN CHECK (ZANRS IN ('ANIMACIJAS','KOMEDIJA','PIEDZIVOJUMU','ŠAUSMU','VESTURISKAIS','DRAMA'))
);
CREATE TABLE SEANSI(
    SDATUMS DATE NOT NULL,
    LAIKS TIME NOT NULL,
    ID_F INTEGER,
    ID_Z INTEGER,
    VALODA VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'LATVIESU' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FM_VAL CHECK (VALODA IN ('LATVIESU', 'KRIEVU', 'ANGLU')),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_FM FOREIGN KEY (ID_F) REFERENCES FILMAS(F_ID),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_ZL FOREIGN KEY (ID_Z) REFERENCES ZALES(Z_ID)
);
```

Comment: By the way, I prefer to declare single-column constraints inline with their columns rather than separately at the end, especially for foreign keys as you can omit the datatype and let it inherit. For example, define the ID_F column as `id_f constraint saite_s_fm references filmas(f_id)` (notice no "integer").

Comment: Hello. In my opinion there's missing information about the movie duration or session's end time to have enough data to prevent from sessions overlapping. With more info, we could create database trigger on `SEANSI` table that could look for potential overlaps before row insert.

Comment: Also `DATE` type can store full time data like `2021/03/31 13:42:10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to ensure that at the same date and time there can not be two different sessions in one cinema hall? How?

You want a unique constraint (or index).  You can declare this with the table:

```
CREATE TABLE SEANSI(
    SDATUMS DATE NOT NULL,
    LAIKS TIME NOT NULL,
    ID_F INTEGER,
    ID_Z INTEGER,
    VALODA VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'LATVIESU' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FM_VAL CHECK (VALODA IN ('LATVIESU', 'KRIEVU', 'ANGLU')),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_FM FOREIGN KEY (ID_F) REFERENCES FILMAS(F_ID),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_ZL FOREIGN KEY (ID_Z) REFERENCES ZALES(Z_ID),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_SEANSI_SDATUMS_LAIK_IDZ UNIQUE (SDATUMS, LAIK, ID_Z)
);
```

The constraint guarantees that there is one row per date/time and zales -- so, one film.

Answer (score 0):

yes a unique constraint on (date ,time, ID_z)

```
CREATE TABLE SEANSI(
    SDATUMS DATE NOT NULL,
    LAIKS TIME NOT NULL,
    ID_F INTEGER,
    ID_Z INTEGER,
    VALODA VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'LATVIESU' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FM_VAL CHECK (VALODA IN ('LATVIESU', 'KRIEVU', 'ANGLU')),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_FM FOREIGN KEY (ID_F) REFERENCES FILMAS(F_ID),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_ZL FOREIGN KEY (ID_Z) REFERENCES ZALES(Z_ID),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_SEANSI UNIQUE (SDATUMS ,LAIKS, ID_z) -- here
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create unique constraint on those four columns. This constraint will force the combination to be unique as you want.

```
ALTER TABLE SEANSI
  add CONSTRAINT SEANSI_unique UNIQUE (SDATUMS , LAIKS , ID_F ,ID_Z );
```

Or if you want to create the constraint while creating table then :

```
CREATE TABLE SEANSI(
    SDATUMS DATE NOT NULL,
    LAIKS TIME NOT NULL,
    ID_F INTEGER,
    ID_Z INTEGER,
    VALODA VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'LATVIESU' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FM_VAL CHECK (VALODA IN ('LATVIESU', 'KRIEVU', 'ANGLU')),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_FM FOREIGN KEY (ID_F) REFERENCES FILMAS(F_ID),
    CONSTRAINT SAITE_S_ZL FOREIGN KEY (ID_Z) REFERENCES ZALES(Z_ID),
    CONSTRAINT SEANSI_unique UNIQUE (SDATUMS , LAIKS , ID_F ,ID_Z )
);
```